# How to synchronise data offline using Phonegap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, data-synchronization

I'm starting with Phonegap, and need to make an application that can be offline and need to synchronize the data.

Someone would have some example ?.

I started studying today and found nothing basic.

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap itself doesn't have any such syncing functionality.

Phonegap is a wrapper for your Javascript application, so it can run on mobile devices as an app.

It contains APIs that you can use to access device hardware.

So Phonegap doesn't really have anything to do with synchronising data - that's really an issue for your actual application, and depends entirely on *how* you developed your Javascript application.

Your Javascript application is hopefully making use of some Javascript frameworks - i.e. Ionic Framework, or jQuery Mobile, or Backbone.js... etc.

So really, you would be better off posting a question like - "how to sync data from a server using Backbone.js"   In which case I would point you to a library such as https://github.com/alekseykulikov/backbone-offline as a starting point.

But if you're starting your application from scratch, I've actually found http://parse.com a great starting point for handling data in Javascript applications.  They have APIs you can use with any Javascript application to store data in the cloud, and then synchronise it to a mobile app.